# Trouble with DIVs

Tags: html

Trying to create a webpage and I'm having a bit of trouble with the divs. The site that this code is for is similar to the old Myspace, so I can't use CSS in the code. I'm trying to create some tables using DIV, and I'm having some issues.

This is how my page looks so far.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the gray DIV inside the blue DIV, the blue keeps cutting off, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's probably obvious and I'm probably an idiot for not seeing the problem. I'm not sure what to do about it though.

This is my code:

```html
<center>

<!-- This template was created by the Angry Hobbit  -->

<div style="width:540px; background-color:#eefbfd; padding:25px; border:1px solid #d5d6d6;">

<font style="width:485px; display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin:14px; font-family: times; font-size:39px; font-color:#000000; font-weight:bold;">FIRST MIDDLE LAST</font>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 

<font style="width:485;display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-family:times; font-size:22px; font-weight:lighter; font-style:italic; letter-spacing:-1px;">» some facts</font>

<div style="width:239px; display:inline; float:left; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:14px; padding:14px;"> 
<font style="display:block; font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:15px; font style:bold; border-top:1px dotted #8ca8ac; border-bottom: 1px dotted #8ca8ac;">basic facts</font><br>
<font style="display:block; text-align:left;font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:9px;">
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">NAME:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">AGE:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">D.O.B:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">BIRTHPLACE:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">CURRENT LOCATION:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">OCCUPATION:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">ETHNICITY:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">MARITAL STATUS:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">SIGNIFICANT OTHER:</b><br>
</div>
```

`

Comment: inside table you should not use div only td and tr

Comment: You are using css in your code already, it's just inline. I would recommend using a .css-file instead and referencing that in the html-file, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: The problem comes from your float : left;

Answer (score 1):

First thing, **you are using CSS** it's just inside your HTML. You really should create a `.css` file and link it with `<link>`. It would simplify your life and make your code much more readable.

Second, making a `div` be `float` remove it from the flow of the page. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

I think this is what you wanted :

```html
<center>

<!-- This template was created by the Angry Hobbit  -->

<div style="width:540px; background-color:#eefbfd; padding:25px; border:1px solid #d5d6d6;">

<font style="width:485px; display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin:14px; font-family: times; font-size:39px; font-color:#000000; font-weight:bold;">FIRST MIDDLE LAST</font>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 

<font style="width:485;display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-family:times; font-size:22px; font-weight:lighter; font-style:italic; letter-spacing:-1px;">» some facts</font>

<div style="width:239px; display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:14px; padding:14px;"> 
<font style="display:block; font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:15px; font style:bold; border-top:1px dotted #8ca8ac; border-bottom: 1px dotted #8ca8ac;">basic facts</font><br>
<font style="display:block; text-align:left;font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:9px;">
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">NAME:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">AGE:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">D.O.B:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">BIRTHPLACE:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">CURRENT LOCATION:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">OCCUPATION:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">ETHNICITY:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">MARITAL STATUS:</b><br>
<b style="background:#d1d3d3;">SIGNIFICANT OTHER:</b><br>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close off the second div, remove the float:left and display it as a block. `margin-right:auto` works well for blocks.

```html
<center>

<!-- This template was created by the Angry Hobbit  -->

<div style="width:540px; background-color:#eefbfd; padding:25px; border:1px solid #d5d6d6;">
<font style="width:485px; display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin:14px; font-family: times; font-size:39px; font-color:#000000; font-weight:bold;">FIRST MIDDLE LAST</font>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif" width:150px; height:150px;"> 
<font style="width:485;display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-family:times; font-size:22px; font-weight:lighter; font-style:italic; letter-spacing:-1px;">» some facts</font>
<div style="width:239px; display:block; background-color:#eeefef; margin-top:14px; padding:14px;margin-right:auto;"> 
  <font style="display:block; font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:15px; font style:bold; border-top:1px dotted #8ca8ac; border-bottom: 1px dotted #8ca8ac;">basic facts</font><br>
  <font style="display:block; text-align:left;font-family:times; font-weight:lighter; font-size:9px;">
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">NAME:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">AGE:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">D.O.B:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">BIRTHPLACE:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">CURRENT LOCATION:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">OCCUPATION:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">ETHNICITY:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">MARITAL STATUS:</b><br>
  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">SIGNIFICANT OTHER:</b><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don not use heavy css style in inline-text, use row and column to space not br and do not give div css give it a class with css. and give the blue box some height, 500px covered that area.

```css
.wbpb {
    width:540px; 
    height:500px;
    background-color:#eefbfd; 
    padding:25px; 
    border:1px solid #d5d6d6;
    }
 .middle-last{
    width:485px; 
    display:block; 
    background-color:#eeefef; 
    margin:14px; 
    font-family: times; 
    font-size:39px; 
    font-color:#000000; 
    font-weight:bold;"
 }
 .img{
    width:150px; 
    height:150px;
 }
 .fact-p{
    width:485;
    display:block; 
    background-color:#eeefef; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    font-family:times; 
    font-size:22px; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    font-style:italic; 
    letter-spacing:-1px;"
 }
 .float-p{
    width:239px; 
    display:inline; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:#eeefef; 
    margin-top:35px; 
    padding:14px;
 }
 .font-times{
    display:block; 
    font-family:times; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    font-size:15px; 
    font style:bold; 
    border-top:1px dotted #8ca8ac; 
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #8ca8ac;
 }
 .block-p{
    display:block; 
    text-align:left;
    font-family:times; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    font-size:9px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <div class="wbpb">
    <p class="middle-last">FIRST MIDDLE LAST</p>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif"> 
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif"> 
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tljLCuq.gif">
    <div class="fact-p">» some facts</div>
    <div class="float-p"> 
        <p class="font-times">basic facts</p><br>
        <div class="block-p">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                  <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">NAME:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">AGE:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">D.O.B:</b>
                    </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">BIRTHPLACE:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">CURRENT LOCATION:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">OCCUPATION:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">ETHNICITY:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">MARITAL STATUS:</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="column">
                      <b style="background:#d1d3d3;">SIGNIFICANT OTHER:</b>
                  </div>
           </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They're unable to use a full stylesheet in their application, which is why they're using the inline style

Comment: can they separate the style with <style></style> and remove it from inline?